# Modifying a script to select divs randomly

Tags: jquery, html, random

i have a piece of modified code that was posted by user: Jashwant.
I'm wondering if anyone might be able to help me modify this further so that the fist div tag with class "box" is selected randomly.

```
var wzprboxactive = 0;
$('.wzprboxbtn').click(function(e) {
jQuery.fx.off = true;
var $wzprboxbtn = $(this);
var $box = $('#area-wrap').find('.box'); 
$box.eq(wzprboxactive).show(function() {
    if ($wzprboxbtn.hasClass('next')) {
        if (wzprboxactive == $box.length - 1) {
            wzprboxactive = 0;
        }
        else {
            wzprboxactive ++;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (wzprboxactive == 0) {
            wzprboxactive = $box.length - 1;
        }
        else {
            wzprboxactive --;
        }
    } 
    $box.eq(wzprboxactive).hide();      
});

e.preventdefault();
     return false;
});
```

For example, I have 2 div containers both with class 'box' the script I assume selects the first container with the matching class and displays it while hiding the other, i'd like to modify this so the first selected 'box' is chosen randomly.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared an example for you to get you started on working with the random function of jQuery:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YEbst/1/)

The jsFiddle is basically self-explanatory but the main idea is the following function:

```
var randomNum = Math.ceil(Math.random()*numberOfDivs);
```

Which picks a random number.

You can then use this random number to 'make' a `div id`:

```
var divName = '#box'+randomNum;
```

Now you have created a softcoded `div id` which you can (from that point on) use in the jQuery selectors. For example:

```
$("#wrapper").find(divName).animate({opacity: 0.25}, 200);
```

Where I labelled the `divs` with the `id`'s: `box1`, `box2` and `box3`.

This should help you enough to do the exact same thing for your case.

Good luck!

Comment: And nobody answers your question because you have 1 reputation and they are afraid that you won't respond or accept any answers. So please prove them wrong!

Comment: Thanks for your help Jean-Paul! I was not able to work further on the project until now. It has worked treat!  I do apologize for the late reply!!!!

Comment: @Nixon No problem. Glad to help you out!